# GCP returning 404 when sending CURL request through tinyproxy on CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl, google-cloud-run, http-proxy, tinyproxy

I have an Alpine container running TinyProxy on GCP Cloud Run and when I send a request from my local machine through this proxy to http://icanhazip.com I get a Google themed 404 error. I've triple checked the app url. The curl command also runs fine locally through the container.

Interestingly when I put gibberish in the part of the Cloud Run URL I get the exact same 404 back.

Curl used from my local ubuntu machine is

`curl --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' --proxy https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app http://icanhazip.com/ -v`

and the output is

```
*   Trying 216.239.36.53:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app (216.239.36.53) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Proxy certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.a.run.app
*  start date: Nov 20 08:02:20 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 12 08:02:19 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app" matched cert's "*.a.run.app"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1C3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET http://icanhazip.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: icanhazip.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Length: 1561
< Date: Sat, 23 Dec 2023 20:56:46 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
* Connection #0 to host xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.a.run.app left intact
```

TinyProxy config is

```
##
## tinyproxy.conf -- tinyproxy daemon configuration file
##
## This example tinyproxy.conf file contains example settings
## with explanations in comments. For decriptions of all
## parameters, see the tinyproxy.conf(5) manual page.
##

#
# User/Group: This allows you to set the user and group that will be
# used for tinyproxy after the initial binding to the port has been done
# as the root user. Either the user or group name or the UID or GID
# number may be used.
#
User nobody
Group nobody

#
# Port: Specify the port which tinyproxy will listen on.  Please note
# that should you choose to run on a port lower than 1024 you will need
# to start tinyproxy using root.
#
Port 8080

#
# Listen: If you have multiple interfaces this allows you to bind to
# only one. If this is commented out, tinyproxy will bind to all
# interfaces present.
#
#Listen 192.168.0.1

#
# Bind: This allows you to specify which interface will be used for
# outgoing connections.  This is useful for multi-home'd machines where
# you want all traffic to appear outgoing from one particular interface.
#
#Bind 192.168.0.1

#
# BindSame: If enabled, tinyproxy will bind the outgoing connection to the
# ip address of the incoming connection.
#
#BindSame yes

#
# Timeout: The maximum number of seconds of inactivity a connection is
# allowed to have before it is closed by tinyproxy.
#
Timeout 600

#
# ErrorFile: Defines the HTML file to send when a given HTTP error
# occurs.  You will probably need to customize the location to your
# particular install.  The usual locations to check are:
#   /usr/local/share/tinyproxy
#   /usr/share/tinyproxy
#   /etc/tinyproxy
#
#ErrorFile 400 "@pkgdatadir@/400.html"
#ErrorFile 502 "@pkgdatadir@/502.html"
#ErrorFile 503 "@pkgdatadir@/503.html"
#ErrorFile 403 "@pkgdatadir@/403.html"
#ErrorFile 408 "@pkgdatadir@/408.html"

#
# DefaultErrorFile: The HTML file that gets sent if there is no
# HTML file defined with an ErrorFile keyword for the HTTP error
# that has occured.
#
DefaultErrorFile "@pkgdatadir@/default.html"

#
# StatHost: This configures the host name or IP address that is treated
# as the stat host: Whenever a request for this host is received,
# Tinyproxy will return an internal statistics page instead of
# forwarding the request to that host.  The default value of StatHost is
# @TINYPROXY_STATHOST@.
#
#StatHost "@TINYPROXY_STATHOST@"
#

#
# StatFile: The HTML file that gets sent when a request is made
# for the stathost.  If this file doesn't exist a basic page is
# hardcoded in tinyproxy.
#
StatFile "@pkgdatadir@/stats.html"

#
# LogFile: Allows you to specify the location where information should
# be logged to.  If you would prefer to log to syslog, then disable this
# and enable the Syslog directive.  These directives are mutually
# exclusive. If neither Syslog nor LogFile are specified, output goes
# to stdout.
#
#LogFile "@localstatedir@/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log"

#
# Syslog: Tell tinyproxy to use syslog instead of a logfile.  This
# option must not be enabled if the Logfile directive is being used.
# These two directives are mutually exclusive.
#
#Syslog On

#
# LogLevel: Warning
#
# Set the logging level. Allowed settings are:
#   Critical    (least verbose)
#   Error
#   Warning
#   Notice
#   Connect     (to log connections without Info's noise)
#   Info        (most verbose)
#
# The LogLevel logs from the set level and above. For example, if the
# LogLevel was set to Warning, then all log messages from Warning to
# Critical would be output, but Notice and below would be suppressed.
#
LogLevel Info

#
# PidFile: Write the PID of the main tinyproxy thread to this file so it
# can be used for signalling purposes.
# If not specified, no pidfile will be written.
#
#PidFile "@localstatedir@/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid"

#
# XTinyproxy: Tell Tinyproxy to include the X-Tinyproxy header, which
# contains the client's IP address.
#
#XTinyproxy Yes

#
# Upstream:
#
# Turns on upstream proxy support.
#
# The upstream rules allow you to selectively route upstream connections
# based on the host/domain of the site being accessed.
#
# Syntax: upstream type (user:pass@)ip:port ("domain")
# Or:     upstream none "domain"
# The parts in parens are optional.
# Possible types are http, socks4, socks5, none
#
# For example:
#  # connection to test domain goes through testproxy
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".test.domain.invalid"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 ".our_testbed.example.com"
#  upstream http testproxy:8008 "192.168.128.0/255.255.254.0"
#
#  # upstream proxy using basic authentication
#  upstream http user:pass@testproxy:8008 ".test.domain.invalid"
#
#  # no upstream proxy for internal websites and unqualified hosts
#  upstream none ".internal.example.com"
#  upstream none "www.example.com"
#  upstream none "10.0.0.0/8"
#  upstream none "192.168.0.0/255.255.254.0"
#  upstream none "."
#
#  # connection to these boxes go through their DMZ firewalls
#  upstream http cust1_firewall:8008 "testbed_for_cust1"
#  upstream http cust2_firewall:8008 "testbed_for_cust2"
#
#  # default upstream is internet firewall
#  upstream http firewall.internal.example.com:80
#
# You may also use SOCKS4/SOCKS5 upstream proxies:
#  upstream socks4 127.0.0.1:9050
#  upstream socks5 socksproxy:1080
#
# The LAST matching rule wins the route decision.  As you can see, you
# can use a host, or a domain:
#  name     matches host exactly
#  .name    matches any host in domain "name"
#  .        matches any host with no domain (in 'empty' domain)
#  IP/bits  matches network/mask
#  IP/mask  matches network/mask
#
#Upstream http some.remote.proxy:port

#
# MaxClients: This is the absolute highest number of threads which will
# be created. In other words, only MaxClients number of clients can be
# connected at the same time.
#
MaxClients 100

#
# Allow: Customization of authorization controls. If there are any
# access control keywords then the default action is to DENY. Otherwise,
# the default action is ALLOW.
#
# The order of the controls are important. All incoming connections are
# tested against the controls based on order.
#
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow 0.0.0.0/0
Allow ::1

# BasicAuth: HTTP "Basic Authentication" for accessing the proxy.
# If there are any entries specified, access is only granted for authenticated
# users.
#BasicAuth lolzor yehbaby

#
# AddHeader: Adds the specified headers to outgoing HTTP requests that
# Tinyproxy makes. Note that this option will not work for HTTPS
# traffic, as Tinyproxy has no control over what headers are exchanged.
#
#AddHeader "X-My-Header" "Powered by Tinyproxy"

#
# ViaProxyName: The "Via" header is required by the HTTP RFC, but using
# the real host name is a security concern.  If the following directive
# is enabled, the string supplied will be used as the host name in the
# Via header; otherwise, the server's host name will be used.
#
ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"

#
# DisableViaHeader: When this is set to yes, Tinyproxy does NOT add
# the Via header to the requests. This virtually puts Tinyproxy into
# stealth mode. Note that RFC 2616 requires proxies to set the Via
# header, so by enabling this option, you break compliance.
# Don't disable the Via header unless you know what you are doing...
#
#DisableViaHeader Yes

#
# Filter: This allows you to specify the location of the filter file.
#
#Filter "@pkgsysconfdir@/filter"

#
# FilterURLs: Filter based on URLs rather than domains.
#
#FilterURLs On

#
# FilterType: Use bre (default), ere, or fnmatch for filtering.
#
#FilterType fnmatch

#
# FilterCaseSensitive: Use case sensitive regular expressions.
#
#FilterCaseSensitive On

#
# FilterDefaultDeny: Change the default policy of the filtering system.
# If this directive is commented out, or is set to "No" then the default
# policy is to allow everything which is not specifically denied by the
# filter file.
#
# However, by setting this directive to "Yes" the default policy becomes
# to deny everything which is _not_ specifically allowed by the filter
# file.
#
#FilterDefaultDeny Yes

#
# Anonymous: If an Anonymous keyword is present, then anonymous proxying
# is enabled.  The headers listed are allowed through, while all others
# are denied. If no Anonymous keyword is present, then all headers are
# allowed through.  You must include quotes around the headers.
#
# Most sites require cookies to be enabled for them to work correctly, so
# you will need to allow Cookies through if you access those sites.
#
#Anonymous "Host"
#Anonymous "Authorization"
#Anonymous "Cookie"

#
# ConnectPort: This is a list of ports allowed by tinyproxy when the
# CONNECT method is used.  To disable the CONNECT method altogether, set
# the value to 0.  If no ConnectPort line is found, all ports are
# allowed.
#
# The following two ports are used by SSL.
#
#ConnectPort 443
#ConnectPort 563

#
# Configure one or more ReversePath directives to enable reverse proxy
# support. With reverse proxying it's possible to make a number of
# sites appear as if they were part of a single site.
#
# If you uncomment the following two directives and run tinyproxy
# on your own computer at port 8888, you can access Google using
# http://localhost:8888/google/ and Wired News using
# http://localhost:8888/wired/news/. Neither will actually work
# until you uncomment ReverseMagic as they use absolute linking.
#
#ReversePath "/google/" "http://www.google.com/"
#ReversePath "/wired/"  "http://www.wired.com/"

#
# When using tinyproxy as a reverse proxy, it is STRONGLY recommended
# that the normal proxy is turned off by uncommenting the next directive.
#
#ReverseOnly Yes

#
# Use a cookie to track reverse proxy mappings. If you need to reverse
# proxy sites which have absolute links you must uncomment this.
#
#ReverseMagic Yes

#
# The URL that's used to access this reverse proxy. The URL is used to
# rewrite HTTP redirects so that they won't escape the proxy. If you
# have a chain of reverse proxies, you'll need to put the outermost
# URL here (the address which the end user types into his/her browser).
#
# If not set then no rewriting occurs.
#
#ReverseBaseURL "http://localhost:8888/"
```

DockerFile is

```
# Use Alpine Linux as the base image
FROM alpine:latest

# Install Tinyproxy
RUN apk --no-cache add tinyproxy

COPY tinyproxy.conf /etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf

# Expose the Tinyproxy port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start Tinyproxy
CMD ["tinyproxy", "-d"]
```

Comment: This will not work. In front of the Cloud Run instance is the Google Frontend (GFE). The GFE will receive the curl request and parse the HTTP method and headers. If the minimum checks are good, then a connection to your instance is opened. Check the Cloud Run logs, but the request will not get past the GFE, which means your HTTP proxy never sees the request.